# Why mongoose.model('Model').Schema is going wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I can't find what I'm doing wrong...
I'm trying to define sub-docs in mongoose models, but when I split Schema definitions into another file, childrens model aren't respected.

First, defining a Comment schema:

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
    "text": { type: String },
    "created_on": { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

Next, creating another schema by loading from mongoose.model() (like we would loading it from another file

```
var CommentSchema2 = mongoose.model('Comment').Schema;
```

Now defining parent schema:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    "title": { type: String },
    "content": { type: String },
    "comments": [ CommentSchema ],
    "comments2": [ CommentSchema2 ]
});
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

And some tests

```
var post = new Post({
    title: "Hey !",
    content: "nothing else matter"
});

console.log(post.comments);  // []
console.log(post.comments2); // [ ]  // <-- space difference

post.comments.unshift({ text: 'JOHN' }); 
post.comments2.unshift({ text: 'MICHAEL' }); 

console.log(post.comments);  // [{ text: 'JOHN', _id: 507cc0511ef63d7f0c000003,  created_on: Tue Oct 16 2012 04:07:13 GMT+0200 (CEST) }]
console.log(post.comments2); // [ [object Object] ] 

post.save(function(err, post){

    post.comments.unshift({ text: 'DOE' });
    post.comments2.unshift({ text: 'JONES' });

    console.log(post.comments[0]); // { text: 'DOE', _id: 507cbecd71637fb30a000003,  created_on: Tue Oct 16 2012 04:07:13 GMT+0200 (CEST) } // :-)
    console.log(post.comments2[0]); // { text: 'JONES' }  // :'-(

    post.save(function (err, p) {
        if (err) return handleError(err)

        console.log(p);
    /*
    { __v: 1,
      title: 'Hey !',
      content: 'nothing else matter',
      _id: 507cc151326266ea0d000002,
      comments2: [ { text: 'JONES' }, { text: 'MICHAEL' } ],
      comments:
       [ { text: 'DOE',
           _id: 507cc151326266ea0d000004,
           created_on: Tue Oct 16 2012 04:07:13 GMT+0200 (CEST) },
         { text: 'JOHN',
           _id: 507cc151326266ea0d000003,
           created_on: Tue Oct 16 2012 04:07:13 GMT+0200 (CEST) } ] }
    */

        p.remove();
    });    
});
```

As you can see, with CommentSchema, ids and default properties are correctly set. But with CommentSchema2, the loaded one, it's going wrong.

I've tried to use a 'population' version but it's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to have to use another collection.

Does anyone of you know what's wrong ? Thanks !

mongoose v3.3.1

nodejs v0.8.12

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/de43219d01f0266d1adf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Schema object of a Model is accessible as [`Model.schema`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-schema), not `Model.Schema`.

So change line 20 of your gist to:

```
var CommentSchema2 = mongoose.model('Comment').schema;
```